# What is the correct way to create an animation in parallel using the result of NDSolve?

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, parallelization

For example, in the following code `ParallelTable` takes 23 minutes:

```
R = 
 Annulus[{-0.9`, -1.95`}, {1.6`, 6.5`}];
soln = NDSolveValue[
     {I*D[u[t, x, y], t] + Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
         NeumannValue[0, True], u[0, x, y] == 
         Exp[-((x - 2/3)^2 + (y - Pi/2)^2)]/Pi}, u, 
     {t, 0., 20.}, Element[{x, y}, R]]
imgs = ParallelTable[
  Plot3D[Abs[soln[t, x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] R, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1/3}, PlotPoints -> 100], {t, 0, 15}];
ListAnimate[imgs]
```

while `Table` takes about 20 seconds. In a real situation, the animation must have many more frames, with `dt = 0.1`. Out of curiosity I waited, and after several hours the kernel crashed somewhere in triangleWolfram.dll as it does about 10% of the time I try to use FEM. I also tried using `NDSolve` with `Evaluate` inside the `Plot3D`, with the same results.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but using a mesh in place of R for the plots speeds things up. Something like this: `mesh = soln["ElementMesh"];
imgs = Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[soln[t, x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1/3}, PlotPoints -> 20], {t, 0, 15}];` For demonstration purposes I reduced the plot points, but you can increase them again.